# Without elaborate if clauses, how can I find array matches between two array subvalues in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I need to find matching items in an array based on min and max values in PHP.  Short of an elaborate foreach,if,elseif,then clause, how can I efficiently get matching rows?

For example...  Given array `$arr` (below), and the number `4`, how can I return array rows `1`,`2`, and `3`?

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array( 'min' => 1,     'max' => 1,     'name' => 'alpha'),
    1 => array( 'min' => 1,     'max' => 9,     'name' => 'beta'),
    2 => array( 'min' => 1,     'max' => 19,    'name' => 'gamma'),
    3 => array( 'min' => 2,     'max' => 29,    'name' => 'delta'),
    4 => array( 'min' => 10,    'max' => 100,   'name' => 'epsilon'),
    5 => array( 'min' => 20,    'max' => 100,   'name' => 'zeta'),
    6 => array( 'min' => 30,    'max' => 100,   'name' => 'eta')
);
```

I'm hoping to turn this into a function.  Something like this:

```
function findMatchingRows($n) {
    $arr = /*** see above ***/;
    /*** your answer! ***/
    return $matchingRows;
}

$n = 12;
print_r(findMatchingRows($n));
```

Expected result would be for above should be rows `2`, `3`, and `4`.  But I would expect it to work for any integer between 1 and 100.

Comment: What's wrong with a `foreach`? It doesn't seem like it would have to be all that elaborate...

Comment: Given the elegance of `array_filter`, why would you choose `foreach`?  And what if my real life scenario had hundreds of items in the `$arr` instead of 7?  `Foreach` loops or lengthy `if`/`elseif`/`then` clauses are cumbersome if not absolutely necessary.  The solution below demonstrates this perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$number = 4;
$result = array_filter($arr, function ($elem) use ($number) {
   return $elem['min'] <= $number && $number <= $elem['max'];
});
```